# bash export all environment variable with certain prefix to folder

Tags: bash, shell, continuous-integration, gitlab

i'm working on my cicd in gitlab.

I have set up many environment variables, most of which are standard string/numbers. What I've done is to prefix them with "APP_" so that I can properly export to my project during cicd only the required variables. I do it this way:

```
export | grep APP_ | sed -e 's/APP_//g' | sed -e 's/declare -x //g' > ./app/settings/.env
```

This will basically take all the environement variables with APP_, remove the APP_, and store all of them in a file in ./app/settings/.env

This works like a charm

Now I'd like to do something similar for my file environment variables. What I've done is creating with a "FILE_" prefix, so I'd like to:

- create one file per environement variable starting with "FILE_", naming the file as the environment variable name (but without the prefix FILE_)
- store the files in .app/settings/files

How should I do so ?

At the moment i'm doing one by one but this isn't what I'd like:

```
echo "$FILE_MY_CERTIFICATE" > "./app/settings/files/my_certificate"
```

P.S. For those experts in gitlab env variables, I'm doing like this because I'm unable to use the standard "file" environement variable feature integrated in gitlab. The variables aren't in my build project so I'd like to find a workaround to suit my needs.

Comment: `I'm unable to use the standard "file" environement variable feature integrated in gitlab` what is that "standard file environment variable feature"? Please explain. What are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: Nitpick: you can fuse both sed calls into one: `sed -e 's/APP_//g;s/declare -x //g'` or better yet `sed -e's/APP_/declare -x//g'`.

Answer (score -1):

> I do it this way:

Forget your code. It's just:

```
declare -p "${!APP_@}" > ./app/settings/.env
```

If you really specifically  *want* to really parse something like `export`, use `env -0`.

> How should I do so ?

```
declare -p "${!FILE_@}" > ./app/settings/files
```

I believe this may be a XY question and you should instead rethink your algorithm to use arrays or associative arrays instead.

Comment: One issue with `"${!APP_@}"` is it includes local variables (non-exported) as well.

Comment: it doesn't work.
declare -p "${!APP_@}" > ./app/settings/.env does export only the variable with APP_, but doesn't remove the APP_ from the variable name.
Also, it adds a "declare -x" to every lines which python dotenv doesn't know to parse... It can only parse with leading "export" or nothing, not "declare - x"

for files it doesn't work as it tries to create a file "files" whereas I'd like to create files in the folder "files" for all env variable with FILE_ as prefix.